# Is OPcache caches required and included php files too?

Tags: php, opcache

I have many classes and php files included to another php files.I use OPcache, but I suspect that it doesn't cache all that included php files. Is that true? If yes, then how to turn on this files caching too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally we use Opcache for caching the complied opcode so that when the same script will run it won’t compile the script again and serves it from cache.

For this you have to enable Opcache in php.ini which will affect your whole application.

opcache.enable = 1;

If you want to achieve this on script to script basis, then no need to enable in php.ini, rather you can set it using ini.set() method.

Now when you want to enable page cache using Opcache which is available from PHP 7.0 onwards, you can do this by enabling this on php.ini or using ini.set() and setting up your cache directory, like below.

opcache.file_cache = “cache_directory”;

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what OPcache is used for. It caches any included files (both php and others: css, tpl, etc).

If you are in a doubt about a certain file not being cached, just check the output of the function [opcache_get_status()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.opcache-get-status.php), it will provide you with a comprehensive report on the cache, including information on each individual cached file.

```
<?php

echo '<pre>';
print_r( opcache_get_status() );
echo '</pre>';
```